# Use of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties

I am starting to learn Spring annotations. I'm currently using the `@PropertySource` annotation in my Configuration Class to resolve properties values and everything works fine, but then I read about `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

When or why I should use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `@PropertySource` javadoc

> ...
> Note, however, that explicit registration
> of a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` via a static `@Bean`
> method is typically only required if you need to customize configuration such as the placeholder syntax, etc. See the "Working with externalized values" section of Configuration `@Configuration`'s javadocs and "a note on BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods of Bean `@Bean`'s javadocs for details and examples. Specifically, if no bean post-processor (such as a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`) has registered an embedded value resolver for the `ApplicationContext`, Spring will register a default embedded value resolver which resolves placeholders against property sources registered in the `Environment`.
> ...

Well, if simple words if you need set up or get more control over property configuration bean such as `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` you could define it. Otherwise it can be ommited.**But if you use version of Spring prior 4.3.0, this bean has to be declared for resolve `@Value`.**

For get more details:

- [6.Configuration using Raw Beans in Spring 3.0 – the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)
- [javadoc @PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

I hope it'll a little help you)